# How to Get Issue Activity with Forget Autodesk BIM API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

[image: Issue activity visualization on Autodesk BIM 360]

Using the BIM 360 I can check all activities regarding a specific issue, like the image above.

How can I get this same information with the BIM 360 API?

I have checked out in https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/field-issues-:id-GET/, and also in the others endpoints regarding Issue on this API as well, but I didn't found anything :(

Comment: You can spy the nested endpoints in the response of the endpoint you listed. As far as I know there is no way of extracting the activities yet but looking at the nested relationship 'activity_bracnhes' this might be a possibility in the future. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, BIM360 API doesn't support querying such information currently. You may contact forge[dot]help[AT]autodesk[Dot]com sharing your idea and what you're concerning. We're glad to hear customer voice. Cheers!